# Initializing values to two dimensional array

Tags: python, arraylist

program

```
ini=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
count=0
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        init[i,j]=ini[count]
        count+=1
print(init)
```

expected output:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Comment: `init[i,j]` is this `numpy` ?

Comment: what do you expect `init[i,j]` to do?

Comment: init=[[3,4],[1,2]]  i expect init[0,1] will return value of 4

Answer (score 0):

Note that in basic python you cannot do `init[i,j]`, it's rather `int[i][j]`.

What about using `itertools.count` in a nested list comprehension instead:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.count(1)

# or: c = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6]) if data can be anything

result = [[next(c) for _ in range(0,2)] for _ in range(0,2)]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: import itertools
ini=[1,25,36,7,5,6,7,8,9]
count=0
c=itertools.count(0)
init= [[ini[next(c)]for i in range(2)]for j in range(2)]
print(init)

Comment: ?? `c = iter(ini)` in your case. and no need for `itertools.count` then.

Answer (score 0):

## The expected answer was this

```
import itertools
ini=[1,25,36,7,5,6,7,8,9]
count=0
c=itertools.count(0)
init= [[ini[next(c)]for i in range(2)]for j in range(2)]
print(init)
```

## expected output:[[1,25],[36,7]]